# Redirect document root within VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I am trying to redirect my domain to a new *document root* if a cookie value is something. I did setup the rewrite and it works fine.

```
RewriteLog "/home/user/dev/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^new_layout_v1_dev$
RewriteCond $1 !^php5.fastcgi [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /home/user/dev/user.dev/htdocs/$1 [C]
```

The problem I have is that the site has a `rewrite.conf` configuration file to rewrite SEO friendly URL's. When the document root redirect does redirect me to a new document root then it does not load the next rewrite's or the config in the new document root.

Errors:

```
The requested URL /testime-pilte-2655600.html was not found on this server.
```

As we use SEO friendly URLs in our webapp and redirect them via rewrite rules to the right php file, then when `rewrite.conf` is not loaded, the web page will show `not found` error.

So my question is, how could I make document root rewrite work so that it will load the new document root rewrite config as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the rewrites I ended up with and they work:

```
# Rewrite to old design
RewriteCond $1 !^php5.fastcgi [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^((?!new_layout).)*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /home/user/dev/user.dev/htdocs/$1 [L]

# Rewrite to new design
RewriteCond $1 !^php5.fastcgi [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^new_layout$ 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /home/user/dev/user.dev/htdocs/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `rewrite.conf` is being included in a `<Directory>` tag or has its rewrites contained within a `<Directory>` tag, try moving it out of that and just residing at the VirtualHost level.